# Expectation of Gamma times S$^2$ in Black-Scholes model

Tags: black-scholes, gamma, vega

Can somebody prove that:

$$E[S_t^2 \times \Gamma(t,S_t)] = S_0^2 \times \Gamma(0,S_0)$$

where $S_t$ follows a lognormal process as in the Black-Scholes model, and Gamma is the second derivative $\partial^2 C/\partial S^2$ of the option price with respect to S.

I can see it is true using simulation, but I can't prove it. It seems to be true for the Vega as well.

Answer (score 14):

What you have to do is to show that the dollar gamma satisfies the Black-Scholes PDE. Using Feynman-Kac it then follows that the dollar gamma is an expectation of a "payoff", just like the Black-Scholes claim price is an expectation of a payoff. And if something is the expectation of a payoff then it's a martingale.

Actually, you don't need the Black-Scholes assumption. This will work for any model (LV, SV, LSV...).

I'll leave the above for you to carry out. What I'd like to show is a nice little trick using the homogeneity property of the Black-Scholes price formula: Denoting partial derivatives by subscripts, the homogeneity of the BS call price function means that
$$
C = SC_S + KC_K
$$
Take again the derivative to $S$ of the above equation, and also take the derivative to $K$ of the above equation. That will give you two equations, and after some cancelling will lead you the the following equality:
$$
S^2C_{SS} = K^2C_{KK}
$$
The left hand side is the dollar gamma. The right hand side is $K^2$ times the discounted probability density. But the discounted probability density is just
$$
C_{KK} = e^{-r(T-t)} E_t [ \delta(S_T-K)]
$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta-function. Hence the dollar gamma is a martingale.

Note that the homogeneity trick also immediately shows that the dollar delta is a martingale as well since $C_K = - e^{-r(T-t)} E_t [\theta (S_T - K)] $, where $\theta$ is the Heaviside function.

Comment: How did you conclude the dollar gamma is a martingale just from whatever you stated above? I've only seen the proof with the full PDE. This way seems much simpler

Comment: Great answer @ilovevolatility.  One quick question :  do interest rates have to be zero to make it strictly true ?

Comment: @dm63 thanks, I have a bad habit of either setting r=q=0 or working under the forward measure. The answer holds for deterministic rates and dividend yields as well, as they are already contained in the equation $C = SC_S + KC_K$ which is the starting point, and I've modified the expectations above in the answer to include discounting.

Comment: @Slade The dollar gamma is a martingale because it's the discounted expectation of a delta function payoff. The nice thing about the above alternative proof, me thinks, is that it shows that not only under Black-Scholes is the dollar gamma a martingale, but under any model that is homogeneous of degree 1 in $S$ and $K$, this includes Heston and lognormal SABR.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: thank you for your answers. my maths are a bit rusty. 1) how do you prove that the dollar gamma satisfies the Black-scholes equation? 2) how do you prove the homogeneity of the call function (C = SC_s + K C_k ) is it valid for any european options? thank you

Comment: @ilovevolatility Should it be that the discounted to time $t$ dollar gamma, $e^{-r(u-t)}S_u^2{C_{SS}}_u, \; u \geq t$ is a martingale? Since the payoff is discounted to time $t$

Comment: @chris see above comment(s) on the discounting. So either you took $r=0$ in your numerical runs, or there is a discount factor missing in the title of your question. Regarding your other question: You can readily see from the BS call price function that $C(aS,aK) = a C(S,K)$ for any $a$. Differentiate both sides of this equation to $a$, which will give you $$S \frac{\partial C}{\partial (aS)} + K \frac{\partial C}{\partial (aK)} = C$$. Then set $a=1$ and you get the desired result. On the PDE question, which part of showing the dollar gamma satisfies the BS PDE is not clear?

Comment: @Quantuple thank you!

Comment: @Slade Yes you're right - I am a bit sloppy with discounting when I think I can be sloppy about it and when it doesn't change the gist (still no excuse). But yes, the conclusion is $S^2_0 \Gamma_0 = e^{-rt} E_t [S_t^2 \Gamma_t ] $
.

Comment: yes sorry my questions was for r different of 0.

Comment: is it exp(-rt) * S^2 * gamma(t,St) which is contant in expectation?  how do you derive the PDE?  do you set u(t, St) = exp(-rt) S^2 * gamma(t, St) and compute the derivatives with respect to t, S and S^2?  i cant find rhe BS pde?

Comment: i finally found the solution with the pde.

Comment: regarding the demonstration using the homogeneity property of the Black schole, the demonstratiin is only valid for call options? right? as u are using the properties that the second derivatives with respect to strike is density function.

Comment: @chris good to hear you solved it by PDE. Gamma for a call is the same as gamma for a put, and since the probability density is the probability density it should also be valid for put or call, right? By inspection of the BS price formula you can easily verify that the homogeneity property holds for puts as well, as it should, so the whole argument works for puts too. Even simpler: think about put-call parity..

Comment: thank you. i was meaning the homogeneity property is not valid for any european payoffs. am i correct?

Comment: @chris Yes, not valid for just any random European payoff (since not all of them have such a thing called strike).

Answer (score 9):

The conjecture is true when the interest rate is zero. Note that, from [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24911/link-between-vega-and-gamma/24913#24913), under the Black-Scholes model, 
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(t,S_t) &= \frac{N'(d_1(t))}{S_t \sigma \sqrt{T-t}}\\
Vega(t,S_t) &= S_tN'(d_1(t)) \sqrt{T-t},
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
d_1(t) = \frac{\ln \frac{S_t}{K} + \big(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\big)(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}.
\end{align*}
Then, it is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
Vega(t,S_t) = \sigma\, (T-t)\, S_t^2\, \Gamma(t,S_t).
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
E\big( \sigma (T-t)\,S_t^2\, \Gamma(t,S_t)\big) &= E\big(Vega(t,S_t)\big) \tag{1}\\
&= E\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}E\left(e^{-r(T-t)} (S_T-K)^+\big|\mathscr{F}_t\right) \right).
\end{align*}
However, we are not able to take the partial differential out as this differential only involves the volatility from $t$ to $T$, and, if we take it out, then the volatility from $0$ to $T$ is involved.

We denote by $\sigma_1=\sigma$ the volatility from $0$ to $t$, and $\sigma_2=\sigma$ the volatility from $t$ to $T$. Moreover, let 
\begin{align*}
\hat{\sigma} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\left(\sigma_1^2 t + \sigma_2^2 (T-t)\right)} = \sigma.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
E\big(Vega(t,S_t)\big) &= E\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_2}E\left(e^{-r(T-t)} (S_T-K)^+\big|\mathscr{F}_t\right) \right)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_2}E\left(e^{-r(T-t)} (S_T-K)^+\right)\\
&= e^{rt} \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_2}E\left(e^{-rT} (S_T-K)^+\right)\\
&= e^{rt} \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{\sigma}}E\left(e^{-rT} (S_T-K)^+\right) \frac{\partial \hat{\sigma}}{\partial \sigma_2}\\
&=e^{rt} Vega(0,S_0) \frac{T-t}{T}\\
&= e^{rt} \sigma\, T\,S_0^2\, \Gamma(0,S_0) \frac{T-t}{T}\\
&= e^{rt} \sigma\, (T-t)\,S_0^2\, \Gamma(0,S_0).
\end{align*}
Therefore, from $(1)$,
\begin{align*}
E\big(S_t^2\, \Gamma(t,S_t)\big) = e^{rt} S_0^2\,\Gamma(0,S_0).
\end{align*}